# VSCode says I don't have Java 11 or later even after installing jdk13, setting up java.configuration.runtimes, java.home and JAVA_HOME and path

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I installed the default java extensions, downloaded jdk-13.0.2 windows installer, updated the path and JAVA_HOME in the environment variables. After searching for answers, I added the settings in VSCode for java.configuration.runtimes and java.home. After all that, when I try to run my java file in VSCode, it gives me the message "Java 11 or more recent is required to run the Java extension. Please download and install a recent JDK... Source: Debugger for Java (Extension)". I'm not sure what I'm missing or what I did wrong. I attached a screenshot of the VSCode settings.

[Screenshot of VSCode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko84d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems restarting my computer took care of it. I verified that java was working outside of VS Code but VS Code wasn't wanting to work with java. No changes were made but when I reopened the project it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add java to Environment Path, `java.exe` couldn't be recognized and used except under the java installation directory, and that's why the java extension think you didn't install the required JDK.

1. Add JAVA to PATH. You can refer to [PATH IN The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

[image]

2. Press **Ctrl+Shift+`** in VS Code to open the integrated Terminal,
   then run **java --version** to check if it's the right one;
3. Install `Java Extension Pack` in VS Code Extension Marketplace, which includes  necessary extensions you need during development.

Comment: I did all those things before asking here and java --version was showing the right version, even though VS Code was still showing the error. It seems to work now, and I didn't change anything since asking. I can only assume that turning my computer off and back on since then took care of it.